# Exact Target "Entity 'nbsp' not defined" error

Tags: php, exacttarget

I am using the Exact Target PHP API starter kit found at http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/api_starter_kits/ , and trying to connect using the sample code. For reference, here is the sample code provided:

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
require('../../00 Includes/exacttarget_soap_client.php');

<?php 
echo '<pre>';
require('../../00 Includes/exacttarget_soap_client.php');

$wsdl = 'https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx';

try{

         /* Create the Soap Client */
        $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

        /* Set username and password here */
        $client->username = '<ommitted>';
        $client->password = '<omitted>';

        $request = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
        $objectType= "Subscriber"; 
        $request->ObjectType= $objectType;

        $request->Properties = array("ID","PartnerKey","CreatedDate","Client.ID","Client.PartnerClientKey","EmailAddress","SubscriberKey","UnsubscribedDate","StatusSubscriberStatus");  

        // Filter retrieve on a particular email address
        $filter1 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart() ;
        $filter1->Property= "EmailAddress";
        $filter1->SimpleOperator=ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;
        $filter1->Value=array("info@exacttarget.com");   //email address to filter on

        $request->Filter = new SoapVar($filter1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"); 

        $requestMsg = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
        $requestMsg->RetrieveRequest=$request;
        $results = $client->Retrieve($requestMsg);          

        /* Output the results */
        echo 'Results:';
        var_dump($results);


  } catch (SoapFault $e) {
    /* output the resulting SoapFault upon an error */
    var_dump($e);
}

/* Output the request and response */
print "Request: \n".   $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() ."\n";
print "Request: \n".
$client->__getLastRequest() ."\n";
print "Response: \n".
$client->__getLastResponseHeaders()."\n";
print "Response: \n".
$client->__getLastResponse()."\n";

echo '</pre>';
?>
```

When I run this code, I het an exception with the message:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx' : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
```

I have used exact target's API before and there were two weird things about it:

1. The error occurs on line 10, and it is triggered in the SoapClient constructor, which is inherited by the exacttarget_soap_client class.
2. I have been assigned a username with a space in it.
3. The original API kit uses the wsdl url https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl , which provides an "Incorrect endpoint" error. So, I have tried it using each of the endpoints listed at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44614/request-was-made-to-the-incorrect-endpoint . Using any one of those endpoints, I get the entity not defined error.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For an s6 instance, I needed to change the url to https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl. Also, it looks like the starter kit has some other outdated code. I mentioned this to exact target and they took down the php (non-Fuel) version.